# How can I speed up this pandas apply operation?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I've written a function which takes a pandas Series (of floats or integers), sorts it, then calculates for each member x the proportion of values in the series larger than x. I'm timing things using tqdm.

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_pandas
tqdm.pandas()

def my_func(data):
    data.sort_values(inplace=True)
    n = len(data)
    # return data.apply(lambda x: len(data[data > x]) / n)  # if not using tdqm   
    return data.progress_apply(lambda x: len(data[data > x]) / n)
```

This takes several minutes to run on a series with ~300000 rows. Is there anything I could do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5))
data.rank(pct=True)
```

returns

```
0   0.2
1   0.4
2   0.6
3   0.8
4   1.0
```